# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "common_types" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Что-то сделал в миграциях, выполнил их, получил эту ошибку:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "common_types" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"common_types"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod,
                     c.collname, col_description(a.attrelid, a.attnum) AS comment
                FROM pg_attribute a
                LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                LEFT JOIN pg_type t ON a.atttypid = t.oid
                LEFT JOIN pg_collation c ON a.attcollation = c.oid AND a.attcollation <> t.typcollation
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"common_types"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
/path/to/project/app/models/common_type.rb:12:in `<class:CommonType>'
/path/to/project/app/models/common_type.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:68:in `block in <class:Post>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:70:in `<class:Post>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "common_types" does not exist
LINE 8:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"common_types"'::regclass
                                          ^
/path/to/project/app/models/common_type.rb:12:in `<class:CommonType>'
/path/to/project/app/models/common_type.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:68:in `block in <class:Post>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:70:in `<class:Post>'
/path/to/project/app/models/post.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/path/to/project/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:9:in `require'
bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Далее откатил все на 100% рабочую версию проекта. Восстановил 100% рабочую БД.

Снова запускаю `rails db:migrate` и снова получаю эту ошибку. Если попробовать запустить проект (`rails s`), то снова та же ошибка про `common_types`. Почему он ругается на эту таблицу? Она создается в самой последней миграции, а до нее еще 10 миграций. Это рабочая версия проекта и до этого всегда миграция проходила нормально.

То есть еще буквально минут 5 назад все работало, а теперь нет. Не запускается даже `rails c`...

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по трейсу, инициализация приложения лезет в модель, для которой ещё нет таблицы, вот всё и падает. Посмотрите по диффам, что вы недавно меняли из этой серии. Или посмотрите по трейсу, как попадаете туда. Займитесь отладкой до SO, а не после.

Comment: @D-side ага. Пришлось закомментировать некоторые связи с common_types в моделях. Но почему это происходит? Я такое впервые наблюдаю за столько времени разработки на Rails... Да и повторюсь, этот код работал, он рабочий. Он перестал работать после "багнутой" миграции. Но я же все откатил из репозитория...

Comment: Кроме комментария выше мне добавить нечего.

Comment: @D-side в моделях как-то можно указать, что эти связи или методы должны работать только после определенной (номера) миграции? Ну или как-то еще можно реализовать проверку?

Comment: Не надо вообще трогать модели в миграциях. Даже если это возможно. Состояние моделей должно быть работоспособным на **последней** версии БД.

Comment: @D-side ага, я понял о чем вы. Но только модель `CommonType` не используется в миграциях. Ругается же на код в моделях, а не миграциях?

Comment: Проследите по трейсу, почему он туда лезет.

Comment: @D-side в трейсе пути к моделям отображаются в куче путей из гема activerecord. Я даже в панике снес и поставил заново все гемы... Из путей проекта - это только пути к моделям, не более. Остальное - это гем. Тот путь на файл routes - там есть цикл, опирающийся на `CommonType`. Но снова повторюсь :) этот код 100% рабочий, так как несколько раз выполнял его (с миграциями). Он просто внезапно взял и перестал работать. Я в это не верю, но это факт. Стабильный проект взят с репозитория же...

Comment: @D-side проблему решил лишь закомментировав зачем-то связи в моделях. Зачем туда сует нос миграция - непонятно... Притом миграции даже выполняться не начинают, а сразу ставят перед фактом, то такой таблицы нет. Ну это просто замкнутый круг. Это ненормально.

Comment: Подозреваю, что для составления маршрутов. Использование модели там тоже весьма необычно. Зависящее от модели должно уже в контроллере происходить.

Comment: @D-side проверил вину роутера (закомментировал в нем тот код) - роутер тут не виноват. Виноваты именно связи и методы в моделях. В модели `Post` я имею метод (scope) с использованием `CommonType`. Но в очередной раз повторюсь - это ненормально, с этим проблем не было никогда.

Comment: То, что оно работало раньше, не поможет вам сейчас. Вперёд на отладку!

Comment: @D-side оцените тот что я написал в ответе, пожалуйста. Может, я в чем-то не прав...

Comment: А, и ещё вот что. С нуля базу полагается накатывать не через `db:migrate`, а через `db:schema:load`. Миграции нужны для небольшого числа переходов между версиями. Хотя в идеале, они и на пустой базе тоже должны работать. В особенности потому, что экспортированная схема не всегда отражает всех нужных деталей (хотя должна бы).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема неожиданно начала возникать в связи с использованием в разных моделях модель `CommonType`. Например, в модели `Post` был `scope` с поиском в `CommonType` (упрощенно говоря).

В решении проблемы с миграциями есть два пути:

1. Закомментировать этот код на время выполнения миграций, а потом раскомментировать (как по мне - плохой вариант).
2. Использовать это: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:common_types)`.

Вторым вариантом я и воспользовался. Все `scope` и прочие моменты, использующие модель `CommonType` я обернул в это условие. Проблема была устранена.

Comment: Устранение симптомов. Работает, конечно, но лучше найти первопричину.

Comment: @D-side подозреваю, что эта проблема была с самого начала, просто был какой-то кэш или еще что. А потом одна фатальная ошибка пробудила недра. Судя по всему в Rails действительно нельзя использовать подобный код. Там был не просто "поиск" (`find`) в `scope`. Пример: `CommonType.posts`. Что тоже является `scope` в `CommonType`.